# How to exclude VAT from order.conf in PrestaShop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I need to exclude VAT from details product line, my customers demands me this way.

I have been researching and I found `order_conf.html` file and it can be modified.
Is there any value to show item price without VAT in product description ?

Comment: How is that a programming question?

Comment: Its I guess i need to edit order_conf.html with prestashop 1.6 variables ...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the tax in the options for each product.
But I think you need a customer specific tax, maybe based on the customer location?!
You can select the tax for each country in the admin panel.

Comment: I´m trying to disaggregate vat taxes from totals. Prestashop 1.6 shows by default item vat price included in each product line.